# Auto generate a partly trimmed email

Tags: email, gmail

I'm developing a message client and I need to auto generate an email on the server and send it to the user each time a new message gets posted in the message client. The email should have the latest message in the top and the rest of the conversation in trimmed form after the latest message.

In Gmail it's displayed as an ellipsis icon [...] that expands on click. Is there some kind of "standard" amongst email clients how to achieve this and what characters or html do I need to include in the email body?

I've tried things like below, but can't get it to work.

```
Latest message

>> Earlier message 1
>> 
>> Earlier message 2
>>
>> etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

What are we talking about here? HTML?  You could use something like jQuery and replace the div each time it is clicked.

```
$( "#earlierMessage1" ).click(function() {
  $('#earlierMessage1').html(earlierMessage1Contents);
});
```

A lot more info needed either way I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm sorry I was unclear. I'm generating these emails on the server. So the question is what text or HTML I need to include in the message body for email clients to regard part of the email (older messages) as trimmed, collapsed or ellipsed (or whatever it's called).

Comment: Are you sending the entire email back each time, or hoping to merge them ? If you're sending the whole email the jQuery would work (if jQuery is supported) - just package each message in code similar to the above.  You could just show and hide divs using Javascript. Again, plenty of ways around it. Depends entirely on how your client is written (and in what language/with what Framework).

Comment: You're totally missing my question. Maybe it's my fault, I don't know how to describe it better. It's not the programming part that the question is about. It's how the email itself must be formatted to include a trimmed part. Is there a "common way" or does each mail service, such as Gmail, have their own way to truncate messages?

Comment: Oh ok. Obviously can't be sure, but I'd say it's all their own (and changes across platforms). My gmail seems to truncate the entirety of every message to the 3 dots.  Outlook Web Access displays the first line.  Windows Live Mail shows the first line, but takes out any line breaks so the text is compressed onto the first line.

Mobile clients then presumeably do something similar, but also truncate the entire message due to data limits - normally at a choice set by the user (I tell mine to download everything). http://www.benchmarkemail.com/blogs/detail/why-does-gmail-chop-your-emails-short